# How to build gem from modified source?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I downloaded https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods locally and modified the source, but now I want to build it into the `/bin` folder to test out my modifications locally. How do I do this so I can do `..../bin/pod install`?

Comment: if it's a gem the normal gem things should apply. I would try 'bundle rake install' read through this: http://rakeroutes.com/blog/lets-write-a-gem-part-one/ http://rakeroutes.com/blog/lets-write-a-gem-part-two/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods is a rubygem, if you are using bundler, specify local path in your Gemfile.

gem 'cocoapods', :path => '~/modified_local_path'

Actually, the CocoaPods document described the way to used unreleased version: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html#using-master-cocoapods

Answer (score -1):

Probably need to modify the Gemfile directly and point it to your repo on git when installing it.